# VS Fails to Launch App on Kitkat Android VM Only

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-android-player

In Visual Studio 2013 Professional I am compiling and running my Xamarin.Android app. It is successfully building and running the Android emulator (Nexus 4 Kitkat).

But the app never launches, we just remain on the Android home screen. And I cannot do anything in VS until I close the Android VM - VS is in Debug mode and there isn't a stop button weirdly. The VS output hangs on `Starting emulator: Nexus 4 Kitkat`. During this period I can use the Kitkat VM and launch other apps so its not frozen.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Some important information:

- The Nexus 4 Kitkat VM was created through Xamarin Android Player.
- If I run any other Android VM I have then VS successfully launches the VM and launches the app. From what I remember, I didn't create these VM's through Xamarin Android Player - so maybe thats why they succeed?

Comment: Out of curiousity, can you run the app via Xamarin Studio with the N4 Kitkat VM? Also what happens if you delete and recreate the VM?

Comment: @codechinchilla Yes the same thing occurs with Xamarin Studio. It just goes to the main home screen and XS continually says 'Starting device'. If I click stop, then say 'Run with' and select the now running VM (it shows it IP address) then it launches the app.

Comment: Definitely odd, sounds like there's some error in communication between VS & XAP, although if it was something like a firewall issue, I imagine it would be happening for all VMs. 

Did you try deleting and recreating the particular KitKat VM yet? You could also try disabling your local firewall temporarily and try connecting then.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue; I was able to update Xamarin Android Player which resolved the issue. You can download the latest version at https://xamarin.com/android-player.